# Rate of surface increase of a sphere related to its volume increase

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to solve problems in the Thompson's classic "Calculus made easy" (not so easy by the way).

One of this problems is to find the rate increase of the surface of a sphere which volume is increasing at $4$ square feet/second rate.

I've found a solution which unfortunatly doesn't agree with author's one.

My solution:

$r$ = radius

$v$ (sphere volume) = $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$

$s$ (sphere surface) = $4\pi r^2$

I "link" the volume with the surface

$$v = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 = 4\pi r^2 \frac{r}{3}= s \frac{r}{3}\ \Longrightarrow s = \frac{3v}{r}.$$

Now I apply the derivatives chaine rule

$$d\left[\frac{s}{t}\right] = d\left[\frac{s}{v}\right]\cdot d\left[\frac{v}{t}\right]
=d\left[\frac{3v}{r}\right]\cdot d\left[\frac{v}{t}\right]
= \frac{3}{r}\cdot 4
= \frac{12}{r}.$$

The author finds $\frac{8}{r}$, but I suspect a typographical error as an other site has found also my result.

Thank you very much to say me if I've made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: The author : I've made a mistake, the increase volume rate is obviously 4 cubic feet / seconds (and not 4 square feet)

Comment: If I understand what you've written correctly, one of steps is $\frac{d}{dv} \frac{3v}{r} = \frac3r$.  This would be correct if $r$ were a constant, but it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Using the natural notation, we have that since $S=4\pi r^2$, by the Chain Rule we get
$$\frac{dS}{dt}=8\pi r\frac{dr}{dt}\tag{1}$$
and similarly that 
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=4\pi r^2\frac{dr}{dt}.$$
Since $\frac{dV}{dt}=4$ (cubic feet per second), we have $\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{4}{4\pi r^2}$.
Substitute in (1). We get $\frac{dS}{dt}=\frac{8}{r}$.

**Remark:** Since we have nice formulas for $S$ and $V$, it is best to differentiate *immediately*. That is often the case in "related rates" problems.

Comment: Thank you very much for this rapid answer. Seems there's as many paths to solution as people trying to solve it.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, there are many ways to do it. In any case the answer is $\frac{8}{r}$. I chose a path that would involve only a small amount of calculation.

Comment: How would you have done derivating directly s as I've done, and without using dr/dt ?

Comment: As was pointed out by Steven Taschuk, the mistake was in forgetting about $\frac{dr}{dt}$.  If you want to avoid $\frac{dr}{dt}$ completely, express $S$ in terms of $V$ by eliminating $r$. We get a not too unpleasant formula $S=f(V)$. Differentiate. We get $f'(V)\frac{dV}{dt}$. We know $\frac{dV}{dt}$. So now we know $\frac{dS}{dt}$ in terms of $V$. To get it in terms of $r$, substitute $4/3)\pi r^3$ for $V$. Slightly ugly computation, but it will work out.

Answer (score -1):

Note: The answer given in Calculus Made Easy-Third Edition is 8/r.
While the answer given for this problem in the 1998 edition (with Martin Gardner's additions) is 8*(pi^.5). I believe 8/r to be correct.